# xamarin pub/sub comunication between devices

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

How would you go about if you would like to create something like:
You have let say 3 devices (can all be IOS or Android, a mix not nececery)

One of the devices would act as a master and the other 2 would connect to it and recive messages.

They are on the same network but do not have internet (so no outside server like SignalR can be implemented looks like)

When they recieve messages (events) they act upon them

I am browsing the web for a while allready but so far failed to find a promissing solution

Does anyone have experiance with something like that? Could I get some pointers what to look at?

Comment: I just need some pointers what to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They are on the same network but do not have internet (so no outside server like SignalR can be implemented looks like)

If every device has its IP address, you can use [Socket](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) to achieve that. The Master Phone act as server-side and other two act as client-sides. And of course connections needs to be established after your app starts.